# Changes made to xaml do not display when running solution

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I made changes to a grid in xaml and added a tab control.  But when the project is opened (by way of F5), the original xaml displays and not the tab control.  Yet I see the tab control in the designer.

I'm at a standstill until this gets resolved.  Thanks.

edited to add:  This appears to be affecting all grids in the xaml.  I can see changes in the designer but not when the project is opened.

Comment: Try rebuild. Also please post part of your XAML with grid and tabcontrol

Comment: See my edits.  Clean and rebuild attempted at least twice.

Comment: Post part of your XAML please. Probably your tab control doesn't have a style during runtime. Than you will see it in a designer only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking a look...

```
    <Grid Visibility="Visible" x:Name="grdDefaults" Margin="0,100,0,0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#6B478E" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#6B478E" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Grid Background="#FFFFFF" Margin="225,37,27,33" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1020" >
                <Grid.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="15" Direction="-90" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="2"/>
                </Grid.Effect>
                <Border BorderBrush="#6B478E" BorderThickness="2"></Border>

                <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="492" Margin="10,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1000" Background="#FFFFFF" >
                    <TabControl.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                                        <Border Name="Border" Background="White" BorderBrush="#3C2F56"
                                        BorderThickness="0.5,0.5,0.5,0" 
                                        Height="40" >
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                ContentSource="Header"
                                                Margin="10,0,10,0" />
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                                                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                                <TextBlock.TextDecorations>
                                                                    <TextDecoration Location="Underline" PenOffset="5">
                                                                        <TextDecoration.Pen>
                                                                            <Pen Brush="#6B478E" Thickness="4" />
                                                                        </TextDecoration.Pen>
                                                                    </TextDecoration>
                                                                </TextBlock.TextDecorations>
                                                            </TextBlock>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#4C3C66" />
                                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,-1" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.2"/>
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#F0F0F0" Offset="0.5"/>
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#F0F0F0" Offset="0.9"/>
                                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#8E88A3" />
                                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#D1CFDA"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </TabControl.Resources>

                    <TabItem Header="Pricing">
                        <Grid Background="#FFFFFF" >

                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>

                    <TabItem Header="Default Shipping">
                        <Grid Background="#FFFFFF" Margin="0,0,0,88">

                    </TabItem>

                    <TabItem Header="Miscellaneous Items Default">
                        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" >
                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>

                    <TabItem Header="Report Messages">
                        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" >
                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>
                </TabControl>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Something got disconnected between the xaml and the build process.  I've made other changes to other grids, canvases, and controls in xaml.  I see them in the designer but not when project opened.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with the xaml designer.  I put a number of messageboxes in the coding to make sure the coding was being executed.  So coding changes are being recognized in the build process.  Xaml changes are not.

Comment: Next day, same stuff.  I attempted to change the xaml on another project and am having the same issue.  With this other project, an error displays  that the g.resources file cannot be found.  No, it's not there for whatever reason.  I was under the impression that this file gets automatically created.  Do I need to reload VS 2012?

Comment: I found out that a splash screen added to the project last week caused the same error in this current project.  The splash screen was removed and the error went away.  However, the xaml designer was left with the issue I posted above.  I checked for all references to this splash screen and all appear to be removed.  Not sure what to do next.

Comment: anyone?  I'm at a loss.